# Translation for all of messages in symfony core or other vendor bundles in REST

Tags: rest, symfony, translation, fosuserbundle, fosrestbundle

I see some messages in Symfony core bundles or FOS Rest bundle that i can't override their messages in `messages.[lang].yml`.

There is some questions on Stackoverflow about translating these messages, But they are about translating these messages in twig.

How can i translate these messages and where in REST responses?

For example:

```
{"code":400,"message":"Bad credentials."}
```